# Is there a standard reduced numbers version of Australian Rules Football?

Tags: australian-rules-football

In several forms of football (and probably other sports) there are standard variants of the game using a reduced number of players. For instance Rugby Union and Rugby League 7s (normally played by 15 and 13 a side respectively). Soccer also has futsal (5 a side instead of 11). In some of the above cases the field is a different size in others it remains the same but in all cases there are changes in the rules in addition to the reduced number of players.

My question is whether there is a similar variant for Australian Rules Football? I do know junior leagues play with less players on smaller fields but that is a somewhat different thing to a 'senior' game just played with less players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standardised? No.

For anything as low as twelve players per team, the rules as they stand work pretty well, although a smaller field may be preferable. For less than twelve players there would definitely need to be some re-working of the rules, but I've never seen any commonly used rules for smaller teams apart from the rules as they stand normally.